# Rails-Active Record query : "where one of ... is in ... "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a "has many through" relationship between Post model and Hashtag model.
I want all posts that match one of hashtags in a list. Currently i use this query:

```
hashtags_ids = [2,7,8]
Post.includes(:hashtags).where(:hashtags => {:id => hashtags_ids})
```

it returns the right posts, but with missing other tags. Example:
Existing post p1:
p1.content = "this is a post"
p1.hashtags = [1,2]

The query would return
p1.content = "this is a post"
p1.hashtags = [2]

Is there a way to keep other hashtags ?

Comment: why is `p1.hashtags` returning an array of `ids` and not the objects themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `joins` instead of `includes` :

```
hashtags_ids = [2,7,8]
Post.joins(:hashtags).where(:hashtags => {:id => hashtags_ids})
```

With this, Rails will use several SQL requests: a first one to retrieve all the posts with at least one of the given hashtags. Next it will fire a new SQL request for each retrieved post  when the hashtags collection will be accessed.